# Using Nested Resources alongside with Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm trying to work with Rails nested resources along side with cancan. I have a `Dog` model and a `Friendship` model.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :dog      
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "Dog"
end
```

Inside `FriendshipsController` I have the following definitions:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :dog
load_and_authorize_resource :friendship, :through => :dog
```

In ability, one can `:read Dog` if it's the same dog, or if they are friends, or if this is the admin dog...

```
        can [:read, :show], Dog do |d|
            d.id == dog.id or d.friend_of? dog.id
        end
```

Some more of the ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(dog)
    if dog.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    else
        if dog.guest?
            # anyone can register
            can [:create], :dog
        else
            can [:show, :update, ...], Dog, :id => dog.id

            can [:read, :show], Dog do |d|
                ((d.id == dog.id) or (dog.friend_of? d))
            end
        end

    end

  end
end
```

The admin can `:index` each dog's friendships, but a dog can't `:index` his own friendships or his friends' friendships.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you show your `Ability` code as well?

Comment: See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/209#issuecomment-609043

Answer (score 0):

You have given "manage" "all" permissions for the admin, so he can see all the friendships.

But you have not given any permissions for non-admin dogs on friendships.

Skip "friendships" authorization for index action.

```
load_and_authorize_resource :friendship, :through => :dog, :except => [:index]
```

In friendships controller, Index action will be authorized based on just the dog model, and all other actions will be authorized based on dog as well as the friendships model.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that in the upcoming days.